# How to do partiton of local disk in Kali Linux 32-bit

Tags: partition, kali-linux, gparted

I want to expand my local disk on which Kali is installed. For that I used GParted and the unallocated space is combined with the local disk, but I am unable to access that. How can I fix that?
[image: GParted screen]

Answer (score 0):

from the pic it looks like the partition is the size you want, (the blue line).

to fill the blue partition with white space that is usable, you'll need to grow the filesystem to fill the partition.

run:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```